# Sequence in $\ell^2$ converget to $0$ if it is summable

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\{v_n\}_{n \in \Bbb N} \in \ell^2$ be a sequence of $\ell^2$ over $\Bbb C$ such that $\lim_{n \to \infty} v_n = 0 $

I would like to know if is true the following relation:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty v_n = 0 $

Thanks

Comment: What if $v_1 = 1$ and all the other $v_i = 0$?

Comment: @EthanBolker let $v=(1,0,...)$ do you mean this?

Comment: Or any sequence with only a finite number of nonzero terms. If you're more ambitious, take the terms of a convergent geometric series with positive ratio $r <1.$

Comment: No thoughts or work on this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not true. Take the series $\nu_n=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: my $v_n$ isn't a sequence of complex number but a sequence of $\ell^2$ or i don't understand you?

Comment: Every real number is also complex, so my $\nu_n$ is an element of $\ell ^2$: the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}$ converges.

Comment: ok thansk.. i have wiswrotten